# How to apply conditional style to unchecked checkbox

Tags: vuejs2

We are running Vue 2.x with vuetify and trying to figure out how to set some conditional, custom styling for unchecked checkboxes on a table for viewing/creating/updating user permissions. The roles are defined something like this:

[image: User Permission Table]

Role A View and Role B Edit are being added. The gray boxes are permissions that have not changed. This is working as desired.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to assign color/style/class to the unchecked boxes so that we can mark revoked permissions with an empty red checkbox so that if manage were unchecked the last row would look like:

[image]

We are using  but have also tried css overrides on . We have tried using css classes, :color, :fill, :style but nothing is working to get the box outline red.

This is what we currently have and is working for the checked boxes:

```html
            <template v-slot:item.view.id="{ item }">
              <v-simple-checkbox
                v-if="item.view.id"
                v-model="item.view.active"
                :disabled="!edit"
                :color="getCheckboxColorForRole(item.view)"
                @click="updateRolesRow(item, 'view')"
              >
              </v-simple-checkbox>
            </template>
```

where getCheckboxColorForRole compares the initial vs current state and returns the appropriate color to display.

What am I missing here?

Comment: To write CSS rules outside v-table with inner components like v-siple-checkbox in slots with scoped styles you need to use the `>>>` deep selector, see https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 0):

can you please provide some code? basically this is style binding

Answer (score 0):

per @Anatoly I looked into the scoped css again and was able to get it to work. But then made it a global css rule so that I can use the scss var for the color and apply this on other pages. This is what I ended up with:

```
            <template v-slot:item.view.id="{ item }">
              <v-checkbox
                v-if="item.view.id"
                v-model="item.view.active"
                :disabled="!edit"
                :color="getCheckboxColorForRole(item.view)"
                :class="[{'group-role-checkbox-original-checked': item.view.originalActive}]"
                :ripple="false"
                @click="updateRolesRow(item, 'view')"
              >
              </v-checkbox>
```

Had to switch it to `<v-checkbox>` since the simple checkbox wasn't allowing me to add classes. Then I checked/unchecked a few times and noticed that the only change is that the `gray--text` class is removed when unchecked. So then I added this css rule:

```
.group-role-checkbox-original-checked i:not(.gray--text) {
  color: $anchor-color !important;
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way to do this I would love to know.